# Проблема при печати html документа!

Tags: javascript, html

[![при отмене и повторной отправке на печать][1]][1][![при первой отправке на печать][2]][2]Подскажите в чем может быть проблема: есть html файл содержащий картинку и текст с кнопкой печать. При отправке на печать 1 раз- в превью печати отображается только картинка. При отмене и повторной отправке на печать- все отображается корректно.
Хочется чтобы с первого раза вся страница отображалась.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Recom-print.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Консультация  хирурга</title>
</head>
<body>

        <img src="http://cardiobook.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/stroenie-serdca-cheloveka.jpg" alt="">
        <button id="print_btn" onclick="window.print();">Печать</button>
            <div id="head">
                    <div id="examinationDiv">
                    <h3>Консультация сосудистого хирурга</h3> <span id="examination"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="patientInfo">
                    <p>Ф.И.О. пациента:<span id="patientName"></span>   Возраст: <span id="age"></span> Дата: <span id="date"></span></p>
            </div>

            </div>
            <div id="all" >
                <div id="inner">
                    <h3>Диагноз:</h3>
                    <span contenteditable id="diagnosis_text"></span>

                    <h3>Рекомендации:</h3>
                    <span contenteditable id="recom_text"></span>



    </div>
</body>
<script src="Recom-print.js"></script>

</html>

<style>
html{
margin:0;
} 
body{
font-family: "montserrat"; 
margin:0px;
}
@font-face {
font-family: "montserrat"; 
src: url("./montserrat/Montserrat-regular.ttf"); /*format("truetype");*/ 
font-style: normal; 
font-weight: normal; 
} 

}

}
                                    /*картинки*/
#image{
    height: 150px;
    width: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:15px;
    /*margin-left:40px;*/
    }

@media print{
    @page{
        /*margin-left:1cm;
        margin-right:1.5cm;
        margin-top:0cm;
        margin-bottom:0.5cm;*/
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: "Veranda"; 
    src: url("./fonts/Verdana.ttf"); /*format("truetype");*/ 
    font-style: normal; 
    font-weight: normal; 
} 
    html, body{

    font-family: "Veranda";
    }
    body{
        padding-top:15px;
    }
    #menu{
        display:none;
    }

    button, label {display: none;
    } 

    #recom_print{
    width:21cm;
    margin-left:0.5cm;
    margin-right:0.5cm;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    }
    input{
    display:none;   
    }

}

</style>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Oog.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXpB9.jpg
```

Comment: если я отключаю css файл- все работает с первого раза.

Comment: в css есть медиа запрос @print

Comment: распечатываю в хроме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас не срабатывают стили. 
Попробуйте добавить !important 
Так же вынес функцию печати до полной загрузки страницы.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Recom-print.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Консультация  хирурга</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="http://cardiobook.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/stroenie-serdca-cheloveka.jpg" alt="">
<button id="print_btn" onclick="print();">Печать</button>
<div id="head">
    <div id="examinationDiv">
        <h3>Консультация сосудистого хирурга</h3> <span id="examination"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="patientInfo">
        <p>Ф.И.О. пациента:<span id="patientName"></span>   Возраст: <span id="age"></span> Дата: <span id="date"></span></p>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="all" >
    <div id="inner">
        <h3>Диагноз:</h3>
        <span contenteditable id="diagnosis_text"></span>

        <h3>Рекомендации:</h3>
        <span contenteditable id="recom_text"></span>



    </div>
</body>
<script src="Recom-print.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        function print() {
            window.print()
        }
    };

</script>

</html>

<style>
    html{
        margin:0;
    }
    body{
        font-family: "montserrat";
        margin:0px;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "montserrat";
        src: url("./montserrat/Montserrat-regular.ttf"); /*format("truetype");*/
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    }

    }
    /*картинки*/
    #image{
        height: 150px;
        width: 90px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top:15px;
        /*margin-left:40px;*/
    }

    @media print{

        @page{
            /*margin-left:1cm;
            margin-right:1.5cm;
            margin-top:0cm;
            margin-bottom:0.5cm;*/
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Veranda"!Important;
            src: url("./fonts/Verdana.ttf")!Important; /*format("truetype");*/
            font-style: normal!Important;
            font-weight: normal!Important;
        }
        html, body{

            font-family: "Veranda"!Important;
        }
        body{
            padding-top:15px!Important;
        }
        #menu{
            display:none!Important;
        }

        button, label {display: none!Important;
        }

        #recom_print{
            width:21cm!Important;
            margin-left:0.5cm!Important;
            margin-right:0.5cm!Important;
            margin-top:-30px!Important;
            margin-bottom:0cm!Important;
        }
        input{
            display:none!Important;
        }
    }

</style>
```

Comment: не работает((((

Comment: @АнтонБогданов. Прекрасно работает, с первого раза, зачем Вы обманываете. Протестировано. Просто скопируйте и вставьте. https://pastenow.ru/ccd2af49d71d8cdc1adbcc82d556078e

Comment: Я извиняюсь, может что-то не так делаю. Попробую ещё раз!

Comment: если стили и скрипт прописаны в самом html- все работает корректно. Но если css идет отдельным файлом- на работает( !important прописан.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/transfer/AAAAAMHgrdCmcQUOfthGJqaJMVlnXtMzEqfM-I3il9jWcQ19xkDj6sg

Comment: все решилось перестановкой последовательности медиазапроса и основного стиля в css файле.